# React/Typescript app build throwing Object (...) not a function in Firefox only?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firefox, google-cloud-platform

Hi I'm currrently working on a web app with React/Typescript based on the react-boilerplate repo using google cloud to deploy.

To deploy, we ran `yarn build` and uploaded the `/build` folder into the google cloud bucket.

The web app currently works on the most recent version of Chrome, the most recent version of Safari, but we're getting this error specifically on Firefox.

````
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    Vz main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:88552
    Qa main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:38421
    Eo main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:38830
    Oo main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:38820
    ko main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:38814
    qo main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:39135
    Vi main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:40366
    Gi main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:40383
    Cc main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:40689
    Ec main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:40663
    Ac main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:40603
    Zi main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:40548
    Rc main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:40780
    jc main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:40785
    render main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:40975
    Uc main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:40861
    qc main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:40727
    Uc main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:40860
    render main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:41027
    aN main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:88966
    8b703812aa8ae3c41814 main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:88972
    a runtime.5a82dd2f84c52f0c96cb.js:1
    1 main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:5309
    a runtime.5a82dd2f84c52f0c96cb.js:1
    n runtime.5a82dd2f84c52f0c96cb.js:1
    r runtime.5a82dd2f84c52f0c96cb.js:1
    <anonymous> main.37e53cd9217f11a35c8c.chunk.js:2```

Let me know if there's any other info needed to help debug.
````